# Lotus rule doesn't work for DELIVERY FAILURE messages

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to create a Lotus mail rule for all mail that doesn't mention me explicitly except DELIVERY FAILURE messages (those special messages from mail router that indicate that a message is too big or Host unknown).

The problem is: DELIVERY FAILURE messages are also caught by this rule as if they had a blank `To:` field, although while viewing them in an IMAP client the `To:` and `Subject:` fields are obviously there.

I even tried to create an opposite rule for testing. It's simple:

```
When messages arrive that meet these conditions:
When:
Body or Subject contains DELIVERY FAILURE

Perform the following actions:
move to folder AAA
AND stop processing further rules
```

This rule is on the top of the list and is enabled, but it doesn't catch the real DELIVERY FAILURE messages. If I try to send to myself a normal e-mail containing this subject the rule catches it.

**Why does this happen and how to circumvent it?**

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because delivery failures do NOT have this phrase anywhere in their content.
The text is created by the form and the column formula in the inbox just for display.
Unfortunately there is no rule that can catch these by default, as you would have to filter for used form or other fields that are not part of the possible filters.

To filter these out you would need to create A custom rule by modifiying the filter form and underlying Script Libraries: this is doable but needs some effort and knowledge of where to put your code and what to modify.